# Wikipedia API extract returning Edit Link in Text

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I am attempting to pull the json from the wikipedia API.  When I extract the main content it shows up on my page but the edit links show up next to the `<h2>` header.  I've included the param `"disableeditsection": false`, as both `true` and `false` but to no avail.  According to these docs: [docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext)

Any ideas on how to remove the `'edit'` text from the extract?

Thank you in advance for your help

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log('ready1!');

    var wikiSearch = "Blue Spring State Park";
    var queryURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php";
    var params = {
        "disableeditsection": false,
        "action": "query",
        "format": "json",
        "prop": "links|images|extlinks|imageinfo|info|url|extracts|text",
        "iiprop": "timestamp|user|url|comment",
        "meta": "url",
        "origin": "*",
        "iwurl": 1,
        "titles": wikiSearch,
        "redirects": 1,
        "inprop": "url"
    };

    queryURL += "?" + $.param(params);

    $.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: "GET"
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log('ready2!');
        console.log('response', response);

        var objResult = response
        console.log(objResult);

        $.each(response.query.pages, function (c) {
            var hey = response.query.pages[c].extract;
            $("#wikipediaImages").html(hey);
        }); //End .each
    }); //End .done
}); //End Document.ready
```

Comment: You can't just use the parameter of one API module (`action` value) with a different one and expect it to work. `disableeditsection` is for `parse`, not `query`. (You'd have seen that, had you checked the API response, which has a warning about invalid parameters.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you use the output from `extract`. This generally doesn't include edit links. But there seems to be a bug on some pages. disableeditsection doesn't apply on `prop=extracts`.

If you want the html as it is, without edit on section links, then use action parse: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Blue%20Spring%20State%20Park&disableeditsection=1

In general your question is unclear what exactly do want to display.